# PHP does not send mail when File attached

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

I have searched through this site but I cant find something related to this. If there is please show me.

My php is divided into two sections, one sends the mail if there is no attachment (works fine)

The next should attach the file and send it with them $msg. This however does not work. I am gonna include the full send mail php here.

```
    <?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

  ini_set("SMTP", '\');
  ini_set("smtp_port", "25");
  ini_set('sendmail_from','noreply@edomain');
if($_POST)
{
    $to_email       = "email here"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here

    $from_email     = "noreply@domain"; //From email address (eg: no-reply@YOUR-DOMAIN.com)

    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
            'type'=>'error',
            'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
        ));
        die($output); //exit script outputting json data
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_name      = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_email     = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $country_code   = filter_var($_POST["country_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $phone_number   = filter_var($_POST["phone_number"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $subject        = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $message        = filter_var($_POST["msg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_name)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($country_code, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){ //check for valid numbers in country code field
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in country code'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($phone_number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)){ //check for valid numbers in phone number field
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in phone number'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($subject)<3){ //check emtpy subject
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Subject is required'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($message)<3){ //check emtpy message
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }

    //email body
    $message_body = $message."\r\n\r\n".$user_name."\r\nEmail : ".$user_email."\r\nPhone Number : (".$country_code.") ". $phone_number ; 

    ### Attachment Preparation ###
    $file_attached = false;
    if(isset($_FILES['file_attach'])) //check uploaded file
    {
        //get file details we need
        $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['file_attach']['tmp_name'];
        $file_name        = $_FILES['file_attach']['name'];
        $file_size        = $_FILES['file_attach']['size'];
        $file_type        = $_FILES['file_attach']['type'];
        $file_error       = $_FILES['file_attach']['error'];

        //exit script and output error if we encounter any
        if($file_error>0)
        {
            $mymsg = array( 
            1=>"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini", 
            2=>"The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form", 
            3=>"The uploaded file was only partially uploaded", 
            4=>"No file was uploaded", 
            6=>"Missing a temporary folder" ); 

            $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => $mymsg[$file_error]));
            die($output); 
        }

        //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
        $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);
        $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        //now we know we have the file for attachment, set $file_attached to true
        $file_attached = true;
    }

    if($file_attached) //continue if we have the file
    {
        # Mail headers should work with most clients
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers = "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()."\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: ".$from_email."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Subject: ".$subject."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$user_email."" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=".md5('boundary1')."\r\n\r\n";

        $headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;  boundary=".md5('boundary2')."\r\n\r\n";

        $headers .= "--".md5('boundary2')."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
        $headers .= $message_body."\r\n\r\n";
        $headers .= $obj."\r\n\r\n";
        $headers .= $product_code."\r\n\r\n";
        $headers .= $cart_itm."\r\n\r\n";
        $headers .= $total."\r\n\r\n";

        $headers .= "--".md5('boundary2')."--\r\n";
        $headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type:  ".$file_type."; ";
        $headers .= "name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Disposition:attachment; ";
        $headers .= "filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-Attachment-Id:".rand(1000,9000)."\r\n\r\n";
        $headers .= $encoded_content."\r\n";
        $headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."--";
    }else{
        //proceed with PHP email.
        $headers = 'From: '.$user_name.'' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    }

    $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

    if(!$send_mail)
    {
        //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_name .' Thank you for your email'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

HTML and JS

```
<label><span>Name <span class="required">*</span></span>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required class="input-field"/>
        </label>
        <label><span>Email <span class="required">*</span></span>
            <input type="email" name="email" required class="input-field"/>
        </label>
        <label><span>Phone <span class="required">*</span></span>
            <input type="text" name="phone1" maxlength="4" placeholder="+91"  required="true" class="tel-number-field"/>&mdash;<input type="text" name="phone2" maxlength="15"  required="true" class="tel-number-field long" />
        </label>
        <label><span>Attachment</span>
            <input type="file" name="file_attach" class="input-field" />
        </label>

            <label for="subject"><span>Please select</span>
            <select name="subject" class="select-field">
            <option value="Order Paid">Order Paid</option>
            <option value="Awaiting Payment">Order Awaiting Payment</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label for="field5"><span>Delivery Address <span class="required">*</span></span>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" class="textarea-field" required></textarea>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span class="loader"></span><input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" />
        </label>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#submit_btn").click(function(){
$(".loader").html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');

        var proceed = true;
        //simple validation at client's end
        //loop through each field and we simply change border color to red for invalid fields       
        $("#contact_form input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").each(function(){
            $(this).css('border-color',''); 
            if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
                $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
                proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
            }
            //check invalid email
            var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
            if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))){
                $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
                proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
            }   
        });

        if(proceed) //everything looks good! proceed...
        {
           //data to be sent to server         
            var m_data = new FormData();    
            m_data.append( 'user_name', $('input[name=name]').val());
            m_data.append( 'user_email', $('input[name=email]').val());
            m_data.append( 'country_code', $('input[name=phone1]').val());
            m_data.append( 'phone_number', $('input[name=phone2]').val());
            m_data.append( 'subject', $('select[name=subject]').val());
            m_data.append( 'msg', $('textarea[name=message]').val());
            m_data.append( 'file_attach', $('input[name=file_attach]')[0].files[0]);

            //instead of $.post() we are using $.ajax()
            //that's because $.ajax() has more options and flexibly.
            $.ajax({
              url: 'contact_me.php',
              data: m_data,
              processData: false,
              contentType: false,
              type: 'POST',
              dataType:'json',
              success: function(response){    
                  $(".loader").html("");
                 //load json data from server and output message     
                if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
                    output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
                  $(".loader").html("");
                }else{
                    output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                }
                $("#contact_form #contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
                $(".loader").html("");

              }
            });


        }
    });

    //reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
    $("#contact_form  input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").keyup(function() { 
        $(this).css('border-color',''); 
        $("#result").slideUp();
    });
});
</script>
```

I have an idea it has to do with the $FILES and $POST but cant get it right

Comment: Something's wrong in your code, Stack's syntax highlighting says so and I can't spot it. Now, does your form contain a proper enctype? Your form isn't posted.

Comment: That is strange, I dont get any syntax errors in dreamweaver. I will edit the post and add the rest

Comment: As per your edit, I don't see any form tags. It needs to have a post method and `enctype="multipart/form-data"`  which is required when attaching files.

Comment: You mean this

$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=".md5('boundary1')."\r\n\r\n";
  
  $headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;  boundary=".md5('boundary2')."\r\n\r\n";

Comment: `<form method="post" action="???">stuff</form>` where is that?

Comment: we are collecting field values using jQuery .val(), we don’t really need a typical HTML form functionality here? I will give it a go though

Comment: Okay I have done this and now I get errors such as undefined index and it is not using ajax. Any idea on where to go from here

Comment: Ìt means your index is not defined...

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an syntax error:

```
 if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
            'type'=>'error',
            'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
        ));
        die($output); //exit script outputting json data
    }
```

See the ' behind POST in the output array.

Comment: Thanks I have added the , there but it still just keeps loading and does not send the mail